# Elasticsearch cost on VM

Tags: .net, azure, elasticsearch, virtual-machine

I want to use Elasticsearch in my .Net core application but I am curious if Elasticsearch is free or not. I've got my own Azure VM where I will be installing Elasticsearch and Kibana but is there any cost associated with Elastic search?

I saw Elasticsearch [pricing](https://www.elastic.co/pricing) link but I assume that's applicable only if I use managed cloud service and want support.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Note that many (azure or selfhosted) database services can do the full text search that you seem to seek from elastic.

Comment: Our current SQL schema isn't optimal. We store complete JSON within a column and utilize the OpenJson() method with EF Core for querying. While this method has been effective, we're now implementing advanced filtering and require faster data retrieval. Hence, we're considering Elasticsearch as the preferred option. Additionally, we might need to fetch data from multiple databases. What would you recommend in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Right. If you are using the  open-source version, using your own servers and manage your own deployment, there is no cost associated with that. However keep in mind there are lot of features which are not available in the free tier.

Check the below link for features available.

https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: And a lot of features that are available in the free tier :-)

Comment: In my case, I simply aim to insert some reporting data into Elasticsearch, utilizing it for advanced filtering, and clearing this data after a span of 30 days. I believe the Free tier would be enough for my needs.